# How to store information about type to use in a procedural macros?

Tags: rust, macros, traits, abstract-syntax-tree

I have:

```rust
trait XrlpType<T> {
    pub fn type_code() -> u16;
}
```

That is each `XrplType<T>` type has a type code that is a small integer (determined by the type `T`).

In a procedural macro that `derive`s from a struct, I tried to sort based on field types:

```rust
let fields_data = fields.named.into_iter().map(|field| {
    // ...
    return Some((field.ty, nth, field.ident));
    // ...
});

/// ...

let fields_data = fields_data.flatten()
    .sorted_by(|a, b| Ord::cmp(&(a.0::type_code(), a.1), &(b.0::type_code(), b.1)));
```

but soon realized that `a.0` and `b.0` are basically just identifiers, not the actual structs, during macro expansion, and therefore I cannot use them to obtain `type_code()`.

So, I face the task how to store that `field_code: u16` (associated with some types `T`) in such a way that I could retrieve it by type identifier from a procedural macro.

The best idea that came to my mind, is to create another procedural macro that *during compilation* would write to disk a database (probably, in `toml` format) that would associate types `T` with corresponding `type_code: u16`.

Any better idea?

---

The thing I am trying to do is to auto-write serializer for struct fields, in which fields are reordered, so that the fields with smaller `type_code` go before fields with bigger one (that's a requirement of the specification that I am implementing).

I want the sorting to happen at compile time, that the problem that I need to obtain the type code for type `T` at compile time, and I don't know how.

Comment: Having the macro write to a file is almost certainly the wrong thing to do. I can't deduce the original problem that your trying to solve, but this looks like an X/Y problem.

Comment: My idea can work only in the case if macro in the source file containing `use` directive are expanded before the `use`d source file. Is it the case?

Comment: Typically, complex and magical things done with macros involve adding a system of traits. Some of the code is generated and some is from trait implementations.

Comment: @PeterHall 1. I added some text below the question to explain the X/Y. 2. I realize that complex and magical things done with macros involve adding a system of traits. But I can't call a trait method at compile time, that's the problem.

Comment: Oh, I can create a JSON (or other format) file that could contain mappings from trait names to values of `type_code`. Then I could both do sorting using that DB and generate traits to export `type_code`s to my app from the DB, too.

Comment: You cannot do that, because you cannot rely on order of expansion. Anyway, what you're trying to do is impossible, but this looks like a XY problem.